# How to use the initialize method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I'm trying to wrap my head around the purpose of using the `initialize` method. In Hartl's tutorial, he uses the example:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
   @name = attributes[:name]
   @email = attributes[:email]
end
```

Is `initialize` setting the instance variables `@name` and `@email` to the attributes, and, if so, why do we have the argument `attributes = {}`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ruby uses the `initialize` method as an object's constructor. It is part of the Ruby language, not specific to the Rails framework. It is invoked when you instanstiate a new object such as:

```
@person = Person.new
```

Calling the `new` class level method on a `Class` allocates a type of that class, and then invokes the object's `initialize` method:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-new

All objects have a default `initialize` method which accepts no parameters (you don't need to write one - you get it automagically).  If you want your object to do something different in the `initialize` method, you need to define your own version of it.

In your example, you are passing a hash to the `initialize` method which can be used to set the default value of `@name` and `@email`.

You use this such as:

```
@person = Person.new({name: 'John Appleseed', email: 'john@some.net'})
```

The reason the initializer has a default value for attributes (`attributes = {}` sets the default value to an ampty hash - `{}`) is so that you can also call it without having to pass an argument.  If you dont' specify an argument, then `attributes` will be an empty hash, and thus both `@name` and `@email` will be `nil` values as no value exists for those keys (`:name` and `:email`).

Comment: Couple more points: the mechanism of using `initialize` is actually a Ruby not a Rails one. Passing an empty hash as the default value for attributes (`attributes = {}`) will gracefully return nil when trying to access a key that wasn't set on the hash `attributes[:name] #nil` - if no default value was set (like `initialize(attributes)` accessing the attribute within the method will throw an error `attributes[:something] #error`.

Comment: Good point - edited to clarify that it is part of Ruby, and linked to the Ruby docs that explain the `new` method and how it invokes `initialize`.

Comment: Michael and tamersalama, thanks for the info. I understand initialize now.